# Parametrized generators?

Tags: python, parameters, generator

I need parametrized generator. Such one that will accept parameters on the call to .next(arg).
In this specific case I want the generator to change with +1 when arg is True and -1 on False.

Is this possible in python ?

Comment: can .send() work in 'for' loop, or it is only good in 'while'

Comment: @user1019129 why would that make a difference? Anyway, you could check that pretty easily...

Comment: How would you send arguments in a `for` loop? The whole point of a `for` loop is to wrap up the interaction with the iterator so you don't see it; where in the syntax would you plug in the args?

Answer (score 4):

Using the [`.send`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send) method on a generator instance allows you to inject state into the generator.  That makes something like this possible:

```
>>> def mygen():
...     i = 0
...     sign = 1
...     while True:
...         val = yield sign*i
...         if val is not None:
...             sign = 1 if val else -1
...         i += 1
...         
>>> g = mygen()
>>> next(g)
0
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
2
>>> g.send(False)
-3
>>> next(g)
-4
>>> next(g)
-5
>>> g.send(True)
6
>>> next(g)
7
```

Note that `next(g)` is equivalent to `g.send(None)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final version :

```
def flip_flop(low=0, high=10):  
    i = 0
    while i >= low and i <= high :
        cond = yield i
        if cond : i += 1
        else    : i -= 1




 In [64]: ff = flip_flop()

 In [65]: ff.next()
 Out[65]: 0

 In [66]: ff.send(True)
 Out[66]: 1

 In [67]: ff.send(True)
 Out[67]: 2

 In [68]: ff.send(True)
 Out[68]: 3

 In [69]: ff.send(False)
 Out[69]: 2
```